# How to Use Sabre EnhancedSeatMap v5.0.0 Service as .Net Web Reference

Tags: sabre

After using the old v2.0.0 we decided to upgrade the Sabre SOAP EnhancedSeatMap to v5.0.0. We use it as Web Reference (not service reference) to our C# .NET 4.5 project. When instancing the new upgraded service with:

```
var x = new EnhancedSeatMapService();
```

Exception:

```
Cannot convert type 'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Amenity_Detail[]' to
'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Amenity_Detail'

error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Price_AndTaxDescription_Detail[]' to
'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Price_AndTaxDescription_Detail'

error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Amenity_Detail[]' to
'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Amenity_Detail'

error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Price_AndTaxDescription_Detail[]' to
'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Price_AndTaxDescription_Detail'

error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Amenity_Detail' to
'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Amenity_Detail[]'

error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Price_AndTaxDescription_Detail' to
'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Price_AndTaxDescription_Detail[]'

error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Amenity_Detail' to
'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Amenity_Detail[]'

error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Price_AndTaxDescription_Detail' to
'ServiceSupplier_Sabre.EnhancedSeatMapRQ.Price_AndTaxDescription_Detail[]'
```

On the Sabre API Documentation there is explicit statement that this version supports .net:

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually because a .NET bug that takes a *sequence* with a *maxOccurs="1000"* and instead of understanding it as 1000 limit, or simply as an array, .NET creates an array of arrays.

```
<xsd:complexType name="AmenityTable">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="AmenityDetail" maxOccurs="1000" minOccurs="0" type="imap-0400:Amenity_Detail">
```

Here is the double array:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("AmenityDetail", typeof(Amenity_Detail), IsNullable=false)]
public Amenity_Detail[][] AmenityTable {
    get {
        return this.amenityTableField;
    }
    set {
        this.amenityTableField = value;
    }
}
```

You can simply download the WSDL with all the schemas and remove the `maxOccurs="1000"` from both `imap-0400:Amenity_Detail` and `imap-0400:Price_AndTaxDescription_Detail`

If not, you can use my modified version: https://files.fm/f/guzxxkkn

Comment: Thanks Wisdoom. what about version 6.0.0 its not showing cabin definition tag